# How does incorporating multi-threading into C++ benefit the performance, and why?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've learnt that multi-threading is when two or more parts of a program can run concurrently but what is the actual purpose of using multi-threading? Why and how does it benefit the performance of our program?

Comment: I have access to 128 core machines. My CFO would not be happy with me if my programs only ever used one of them. You need to adopt a multithreaded model if you want to use the other 127.

Comment: How does it benefit the performance? Usually, I boil pasta at the same time as I am making the sauce. This way, I get to eat sooner. Doing them sequentially will keep me hungry for longer.

Comment: @Bathsheba technically speaking, multi-processing would do too.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica or (more likely in my case) end up with overcooked pasta :(

Comment: @SergeyA - Have you considered that you are maybe using the wrong synchronization mechanism? ;)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica without a doubt, without a doubt. Looks like the biggest issue is with interrupt masking ;)

Comment: Well obviously if you can do two things at once you can do them twice as quickly.

Comment: It might not benefit the performance. There are numerous questions on Stack Overflow that wonder why introducing multithreading into a program causes it to run slower.

Answer (score 1):

If I have a list of say 10000 items that require an operation on each. If I use a single thread for this operation on 10000 items, lets say it will take 8 seconds. If I use multithreading for this operation on a 4 core CPU, This means that I can divide the operation among 4 threads and the cost of the operation will now be the cost of running one 4th of the item which is 2500. The time taken now will be approximately 2 seconds. since each thread is running independently on 2500 of the items making 10000 items. In this way, multithreading can speed up your computation. I am not taking into consideration the cost of setting up the threads.

Another use of multithreading is to avoid thread blocking calls that take a long time to return. For example accept and connect in TCP socket programming. You can spin a new thread to handle that not for the sake of speed but to ensure that the main thread is not blocked.

Comment: This assumes that the OS will run one thread on each core.  There is no guarantee that the OS will run one thread on each core.  Worst case, you have more tasks sharing one core.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, It would be an unusual OS, or an unusual configuration of an OS, if it allowed any CPU to remain idle for any significant amount of time while ready-to-run threads were waiting in the run queue.

Comment: I'm not saying keeping cores idle; the cores running other applications.  For example, one core can be playing music, another doing internet I/O, etc.  So, worse case, the other cores would be busy with higher priority threads or tasks.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, Of course, but in any discussion about the performance of some compute-intensive application, it's customary to _assume_ that the whole hardware platform (or some well defined fraction of it) is reserved for the application unless someone explicitly says otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The *actual* purpose of multithreading is nothing more than what you said: It is a way to let two or more parts of a program run concurrently.

There are many reasons why you might want two or more parts of the same program to run concurrently. *One* of those reasons is, it's a way to exploit the several CPUs of a multi-processor computer system: Different concurrent threads can execute [in parallel with each other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing) if they are assigned to different CPUs.